# ASP.NET Webforms Login not redirecting to page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I've been having major problems getting authentication to work in ASP.NET Webforms the past couple of days. I get past one problem and another pops up.

Currently I have the site redirecting anonymous users to my login page. However, when a successful login is made it seems to jump straight back to the Login page.

My authentication is set up like this in my project root's web.config.

```
<authentication mode ="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I don't have a web.config in the Account folder.

Comment: Can you access the other pages after login?

Comment: Hi. I never tried. A little while ago I rolled back all my changes except one. Originally I had the loginUrl point to "~/Account/Login.aspx". I rolled everything back except for the loginUrl you now see above and it worked. The problem I have now is that nothing I try can persuade any browser to successfully log the user out. It seems to be a problem clearing the browser cache - tried everything I find on here and elsewhere on the 'net and nothing's working. I guess I'll have to post a question about that.